# How to get json from instagram.com/user/?__a=1

Tags: php, json, curl, instagram

I am using curl with postman to get a json from an Instagram user through this URL "https://www.instagram.com/kiddothegame/?__a=1".
It works and postman shows me a json response with info like:

```
  {"seo_category_infos":[["Beauty","beauty"],["Dance & Performance","dance_and_performance"],["Fitness","fitness"],["Food & Drink","food_and_drink"],["Home & Garden","home_and_garden"],["Music","music"],["Visual Arts","visual_arts"]],.....
```

Now I try to do the same request with PHP:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.instagram.com/kiddothegame/?__a=1',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

And the echo result is :

```
string(52678) "
"
```

Oddly all the characters are spaces.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe the request is different somehow. Was this PHP code auto-generated by Postman, or did you write it yourself?

Comment: Also you don't seem to be checking for any cURL errors...

Comment: For me, it doesn't give JSON, it sends me to a login page. I've encountered issues like these before, where it seems like it was limited. Does Postman still give you JSON if you run the request several times?